# Converting @Html.ActionLink to @Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to convert this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", 
  routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
```

To this

```
<input type="button" title="Register" 
  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" }
```

I keep erring out on htmlAttributes. I'm trying to make the first link into a button, but keep the same attributes. Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

The `@Url.Action` has neither a `linkText` nor an `htmlAttributes` parameter. What you can do instead, is use the HTML `id` and `value` attributes directly.

## Example

[Here's a working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p1qKMq).

In the below example, I've done just that and have used named arguments to illustrate the difference between `@Url.Action` and `@Html.ActionLink`.

[LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
    @Html.ActionLink(
        linkText: "Register", 
        actionName: "Register", 
        controllerName: "Account",
        routeValues: null, 
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
```

Equivalent [UrlHelper.Action Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460297%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
    <input 
        id="registerLink"
        type="button" 
        title="Register" 
        value="Register"
        onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(
            actionName: "Register", 
            controllerName: "Account", 
            routeValues: null)'" />
```

Comment: I think Controller name is `Account ` not a `Register`

Answer (score 0):

Html attributes has to be added into html :) like:

```
<input type="button" title="Register" id="registerLink"
  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register", "Account")'" />
```

Comment: Remove one "Register" please, cause it was used for link text, and does not make sense here

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" title="Register" id="registerLink"
  onclick="window.location='@Url.Action("Register", "Account")'" />
```

It will work, i have on tried the other ans. but this can one option.